# Oracle SQL: Replace all non-numeric values, such as NULL, blank or empty strings

Tags: sql, oracle, select, replace, trim

I have a column that is formatted as number but seems to contain some other values as well that are causing trouble with my other functions (Rtrim, Xmlagg, Xmlelement, Extract), leading the whole query to fail (which works well if I take this column out).

Can someone tell me the best way to replace anything in a column that is not a valid number by 0 (or alternatively a placeholder number like 99999) ?

I tried the following but guess this only covers **NULL values**, not **empty strings or blank strings** which I think I have to replace first.

```
TO_CHAR(NVL(a.mycolumn, 0))
```

Many thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, you should be able to use `TRIM()`:

```
NVL(TRIM(a.mycolumn), '0')
```

Oracle (by default) treats empty strings as `NULL`.

Do note that this will trim the result, even if it is not `NULL`.  If that is not desirable, use `CASE`:

```
(CASE WHEN TRIM(a.mycolumn) IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE a.myolumn END)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot for the quick help, Gordon !

Answer (score 3):

Use `REGEXP_LIKE`

For Numeric:

```
REGEXP_LIKE (numeric_value, '^\d+(\.\d+)?$')
```

or with null

```
REGEXP_LIKE(NVL(value, 'NULL'), '^\d+(\.\d+)?$|NULL$')
```